# Why does this React router NavLink either redirect or submit successfully but, not both?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-router, form-submit

I am attempting use the react router link to redirect to the "/SwatThankYou" page after clicking submit for the form. The form is sent as an email to my gmail account using emailjs so, I can see if it is functioning or not.

Here are the imports

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, NavLink, FormGroup, Input, Label } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import groupPicture from "../church2019.jpg";
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';
import './Site.css';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
```

These are the buttons I have tried so far...

**This button successfully submits the form but, does not redirect.**

```
<button type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

**This button redirects but, does not send the form.**

```
<NavLink type="submit" value="Send" tag={Link} to="/SwatThankYou"><button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></NavLink>
```

**This button redirects but, does not send the form.**

```
<NavLink className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Send" tag={Link} to="/SwatThankYou">Submit </NavLink>
```

Comment: Can you please show what you are trying to do at the form will be submit

Comment: When I click the submit button I want the /SwatThankYou page to show.  I am using react-router to go to the /SwatThankYou page but, for some reason it does not show when I click submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Button Link to="/SwatThankYou" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
 Submit                               
</Button> 
</BrowserRouter>
```